# Clojurescript Build with Modules - Constants Table Crashing

Tags: clojurescript, cljsbuild

I'm building an app using:

`lein cljsbuild once min`

where my min config is

```
{:id "min"
 :source-paths ["src"]
 :compiler {:output-dir "resources/public/js"
            :main app.core
            :optimizations :advanced
            :modules {:app
                      {:output-to "resources/public/js/app.js"
                       :entries #{app.core}}}
            :pretty-print false}}
```

I end up with 3 js files: cljs_base.js, constants_table.js and app.js

When I include them in my index.html file in that order, I get a console exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: cljs.core.Keyword is not a constructor
>       at constants_table.js:1

If I add `:optimize-constants` false then it builds the modules correctly.

Comment: I don't think you should include cljs_base.js or constants_table.js. BTW what is `:entries #{app.core}`?